# Add a custom flag to the yarn build quasar command

Tags: electron, electron-builder, quasar-framework, quasar

Currently in our codebase every time you run `yarn build` it builds the application and code signs it. I want to make the code signing optional as it substantially slows down the build process. I'd like to have a command similar to: `yarn build -codesign` where it conditionally renders the extra code sign instructions if used or leaves that part empty if not used.

In package.json the script for build is: `"build": "quasar build -m electron",`

I know which two lines trigger the code signing in `quasar.conf.js`, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make a custom flag/pass in a variable into the build command.

Does anyone have any insight or know where to find an example/that documentation?